# Restrict template friends of a class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class S {
    static const int i = 42;
    template <class T>
    friend void f();
};

template <class T>
void f()
{
    std::cout << S::i << "\n";
}

int main() 
{
    f<int>();
    f<double>();
}
```

All I want here is to allow access to private part of a class `S` to  `f<int>`, but not for `f<double>`. I.e. I want to get compiler error like `'i' is a private member of 'S'` for `f<double>()` line.

How to achive this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The template instantiation is a function, so just name it: `void f<int>()`.

You need a prior declaration, though:

> `[C++03: 11.4/9 | C++11/C++14: 11.3/11]:` If a friend declaration appears in a local class (9.8) and the name specified is an unqualified name, a prior declaration is looked up without considering scopes that are outside the innermost enclosing non-class scope. For a friend function declaration, if there is no prior declaration, the program is ill-formed. *[..]*

(This wasn't the case for the `friend`-inside-template-declaration that you had originally, because templates are looked up a little later in the parsing process.)

Here's the finished solution:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void f();

class S {
    static const int i = 42;
    friend void f<int>();
};

template <class T>
void f()
{
    std::cout << S::i << "\n";
}

int main() 
{
    f<int>();
    f<double>();
}
```

Now the only error is caused by the `f<double>()` call.

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73ef07364e8afd54))

Comment: Where did the comments go, and why? o.O

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I deleted it after reading answer more attentively:)

Comment: @alexolut: It was weird because my comment vanished too!

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare (or just define) the template function before the class `S`. Then you can just say that you want it to be friends with `f<int>()`. Like so:

```
template <class T> void f();

class S {
    static const int i = 42;
    friend void f<int>();
};

template <class T>
void f()
{
    std::cout << S::i << "\n";
}
```